# Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k+1}=\frac{1}{2} $ for $k \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This series  :$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k+1}$ is convergent for every $k>1$ , it's seems that it has a closed form for every $k >1$, some calculations [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E23%2B1%7D),+n%3D1+to+infty) in wolfram alpha show to me that the sum approach to $\frac{1}{2}$ for large $k$ , My question here is :

> **Question:**
>
> Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k+1}\to\frac{1}{2} $ for $k \to \infty$?

Comment: Well it's never equal to $1/2$ so you shouldn't write it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on basic principles.  To that end we proceed.

---

Let $f(k)$ be the function given by $f(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^k}$ for $k>1$.  Clearly, $f(k)=\frac12+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^k}$.

We let $g(k)$ denote the series given by $g(k)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^k}$ and note that $g(k)$ is monotonically decreasing.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  There exists a number $N'$ such that

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2}<\epsilon/2$$

whenever $N>N'$.

We fix $N>N'$ and take $k$ so large that $\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+n^k}< \frac\epsilon2$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
g(k)&=\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+n^k}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^k}\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{1+n^k}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}\\\\
&<\frac\epsilon2+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}$$

We can assert, therefore, that

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}g(k)=0$$

and hence we have

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}f(k)=\frac12$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 10):

Yes of course, we have the following:

$\frac{1}{2}\leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}+\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^k+1}dx\leq \frac{1}{2}+ \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^k}dx=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Now use the theorem of squeezing.

Comment: Thanks for that , can I try to deduce it closed form for every k >1 then i try to take a limit for k \to infty ?

Comment: that also would work.

Comment: I believe your $k$ and $n$ indices are incorrect in the second and third steps?

Comment: yes of course, thank you kindly

Comment: @user51189, I don't think there exists a closed form. Actually for even k it  depends on the number of poles which will increase as k increases.

Comment: It would converge an awful lot faster if you added 1/(2^k+1) separately and then started the integral at 2.

Comment: nice observation, it would be exponential.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla because otherwise it would be false, notice that $\frac{1}{x^k}\leq \frac{1}{x^k+1}\leq \frac{2}{x^k}$ for $x\geq 1$

Comment: oh yeah, you are right, we can just make it $\frac{1}{x^k}$.

Answer (score 7):

Let

$$S_k = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k}.$$

We know $S_2 <\infty.$ Note that for $k>2,$

$$S_k = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{k-2}}\frac{1}{n^2}\le \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k-2}}\frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{1}{2^{k-2}}S_2.$$

This implies $S_k \to 0$ (in fact at an exponential rate). Thus

$$\frac{1}{2}< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k+1}= \frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k+1} < \frac{1}{2} + S_k,$$

and we're done by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I was just working on a way forward that circumvented appeal to integrals and relied instead on elementary analysis.  You beat me to it!  Well done.  (+1) and Happy Holidays Z-man!  -Mark

Comment: Happy holidays back to you sir!

Comment: Hi zhw. can you guide us with the next https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440926/measurable-functions-and-existence-decreasing-function

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indeed
$$
0\le \lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac{1}{n^k+1}\le \lim_{k\to \infty} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^k+1}\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^\infty \lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^k+1}\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
by the dominated convergence.

Comment: You can apply dominated convergence theorem to the series directly, there's no point in introducing the integral.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Ah, you are right :)