# On a conjecture that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, pi, conjectures

I have made the following conjecture, and I do not know if this is true.

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> \begin{equation*}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}2\verb| such that we denote by | p_n\verb| the | n^\text{th} \verb| prime.|\end{equation*}

Is my conjecture true? It seems like it, according to a plot made by Wolfram|Alpha, but if it does, then it converges.... *very*.... *very*, slowly. In fact, let $k=5000$, then the sum is approximately equal to $1.97$, which just proves how slow it would be.

Is there a way of showing whether or not this is indeed convergent? For any other higher values of $k$, it seems that it is just too much for Wolfram|Alpha to calculate, and it does not give me a result when I let $k=\infty$. Also, for users who might not understand the notation, we can similarly write that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}=2\qquad\text{ or }\qquad\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}=2.$$ Also, without Wolfram|Alpha, I have *no idea* how to approach this problem in terms of proving it or disproving it. Does the sum even converge *at all*? If so, to what value? Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I looked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070991/is-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1nk1-frac12-for-k-to-infty?rq=1) to see if I could rewrite my conjecture as something else in order to help myself out. Consequently, I wrote that $$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longleftrightarrow}4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^k+1}\tag{$\text{LHS}=2$}$$ since both sums look very similar. Could *this* be of use?

Comment: Hint: $p_n \sim n \log n$.

Comment: @JavaMan could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: For the numbers I used, $S_m\approx \sqrt m$.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that
[$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) is a divergent series. Then your series is divergent too because, for any positive number $a$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\ln(a)/n}=1,$$ and therefore
$$\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}\sim \frac{1}{p_n}.$$

Comment: I never knew that the sum of the reciprocal of primes was a divergent series. That makes [**Brun's Constant**](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/brunsconstant.html) even more special. Congratulations! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 3):

Numerically, this does not seem to be true.

Considering $$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{10^m}\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}$$ and, using illimited precision, I obtained the following numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & S_m \\
 1 & 0.891549393 \\
 2 & 1.437754209 \\
 3 & 1.787152452 \\
 4 & 2.038881140 \\
 5 & 2.235759176 \\
 6 & 2.397832041
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

After marty cohen's answer, based on the above data, a quick and dirty fit for the model
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{\pi^{1/n}p_n}=a+b\,\log(\log(k))$$ gives $(R^2=0.999947)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.17085 & 0.02635 & \{0.08600,0.25471\} \\
 b & 0.84291 & 0.01302 & \{0.80146,0.88436\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: It appears that by letting $m_n > m_{n-1}$, we have that $m_n-m_{n-1}\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s_n}$is a divergent series therefore if you tend the limit to $\infty$ ;
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\pi^{1/n}=1$
You can see that the above term tends to $1$.
The remaining term is similar to above mentioned divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

If $a > 1$
Then,
since
$p_n \sim n \ln n$
and
$1/a^{1/n}
=e^{-\ln a/n}
\sim 1-\ln a/n
$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n 1/(a^{1/k}p_k)
\sim \sum_{k=1}^n 1/p_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln a/(kp_k)
\sim \ln. \ln n-c
$
for some $c$
since the second sum converges.

Therefore the sum diverges like
$\ln \ln n$.